# getting `Unknown options` error when creating cognito-user-pool using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I tried to run following command to create a cognito-user-pool using aws cli.

```
aws.command(
    `cognito-idp create-user-pool \
    --pool-name TestUserPool \
    --auto-verified-attributes email phone_number \
    --policies PasswordPolicy={MinimumLength=integer,RequireUppercase=boolean,RequireLowercase=boolean,RequireNumbers=boolean,RequireSymbols=boolean,TemporaryPasswordValidityDays=integer} \
    --alias-attributes email phone_number preferred_username \
    --sms-verification-message 'Your authentication code for ${name} is {####}.' \
    --email-verification-message 'Your authentication code for ${name} is {####}.' \
    --email-verification-subject 'Your Verification Code for ${name}.' \
    --verification-message-template DefaultEmailOption='CONFIRM_WITH_LINK' EmailMessageByLink='Please click the link below to verify your email address. {##Verify Email##}' EmailSubjectByLink='Your verification link' SmsMessage='Your authentication code for ${name} is {####}.' \
    --sms-authentication-message 'Your authentication code for ${name} is {####}.' \
    --mfa-configuration OPTIONAL \
    --email-configuration EmailSendingAccount='DEVELOPER' SourceArn='arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:412***092:identity/***@***.com' From='***@***.com' ReplyToEmailAddress=***@***.com \
    --sms-configuration SnsCallerArn='arn:aws:iam::412***092:role/service-role/test-SMS-Role', ExternalId='d611c8fd-0fd1-469a-a5ea-b02186042023' \
    --admin-create-user-config AllowAdminCreateUserOnly=false InviteMessageTemplate={EmailMessage='Your username for ${name} is {username} and temporary password is {####}.' EmailSubject='Your temporary password for ${name}' SMSMessage='Your username for ${name}is {username} and temporary password is {####}.'} UnusedAccountValidityDays=7 \
    --account-recovery-setting RecoveryMechanisms=[{Priority=1,Name=verified_email},{Priority=2,Name=verified_phone_number}] \
    --device-configuration ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice=true, DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt=true`
).then(function (data) {
    console.log('data=', data)
})
```

But I'm getting following error.

```
Unknown options: EmailSubjectByLink=Your verification link, SmsMessage=Your authentication code for tester is {####}., SourceArn=arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:412***092:***/***@***.com, From=***@***.com, ReplyToEmailAddress=***@***.com, ExternalId=d611c8fd-0fd1-469a-a5ea-b02186042023, InviteMessageTemplate={EmailMessage=Your username for tester is {username} and temporary password is {####}., EmailSubject=Your temporary password for tester, SMSMessage=Your username for testeris {username} and temporary password is {####}.}, UnusedAccountValidityDays=7, DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt=true, EmailMessageByLink=Please click the link below to verify your email address. {##Verify Email##}
' stdout = '' stderr = 'usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
```

What is wrong?